Convolution instead of Boltzmann distribution for an ensemble
While I do understand why the energy PDF of a single molecule follows the Boltzmann distribution, I fail to understand why it also applies to ensembles.
In the case of ensembles, the total energy is $\sum_{i}{\epsilon_{i}}$. My thinking then suggests that it is the sum of n independent random variables which means that we would have to calculate the n-dimensional convolution of the Boltzmann distribution. Why is this apparently not necessary?
Clarification:
$p_{i} = \frac{e^{\beta\epsilon_{i}}}{\sum_{i}{e^{\beta\epsilon_{i}}}}$
This would be the probability that a single molecule is in the ith energy state. When talking about ensembles the energy state is equal to the sum of the individual energies and its probability is (according to textbooks) modelled by the same distribution (Boltzmann's). However, I see this as adding n independent random variables which follow the distribution $p_{i} \rightarrow \epsilon_{i} $. As such, these problems are solved by calculating the convolution of the distribution. According to the Central Limit Theorem, this convolution tends to a Gaussian at the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Clarification #2:
Suppose $N=2$ (2 atoms in our system). I believe one would model $E_{j}$ using the following equation if I am not mistaken:
$\sum_{i=0}^{j}{p_{i}p_{j-i}}$ (assuming we setup the system so that $\epsilon_{i}+\epsilon_{j}=\epsilon_{i+j}$)
This is not the same distribution ...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You're mixing up the canonical and microcanonical ensembles. In the microcanonical, total $E$ is exactly fixed, so you must carefully keep track of where the energy is and so have to use the multinomial distribution, which is related to the Bernoulli and binomial distributions. In the canonical ensemble, the average energy is fixed, and this allows more freedom. E.g., the probabilities of individual particles being in a state are independent, so you just multiply them. The Boltzmann distribution is used in the canonical ensemble.

@march thx for commenting. Would it be possible for you to write an answer with some examples?

@march I mean if I were to program what I'm talking about it would be like this:    clear
m = 200; % number systems
k=0.5;
x=1:10;
N=10000;
Z = sum(e.^-(1:10));
p = e.^-(1:10)/Z;
q = cumsum(p);
L = rand(N,m);
for j=1:m
for i=1:N
k(j,i) = min(find(q > L(i,j)));
endfor
[data1(j,:),~] = hist(k(j,:));
endfor
hist(data1*(1:10)')

I was hoping someone else would come along an explain this, since I've been away from statistical mechanics for quite some time, but I think a good example to look through, which illustrates most of the ideas involved, is the Einstein solid.  That page shows the derivations for the heat capacity of an Einstein solid in the microcanonical ensemble (where you fix the total energy exactly and split the energy among subsystems) and in the canonical ensemble (which uses Boltzmann factors and fixes the average energy).
